# Google One Tap throws error with cryptic message

Tags: google-identity, google-one-tap

After implementing Google One Tap I noticed some JS errors on the client side (these client-side errors are caught in the browser and sent to the backend; I can see them in the backend logs but cannot reproduce the issue in the client side) for which the stack trace looks like this:

```
Error: A
at Object._.ad (/_/gsi/_/js/k=gsi.gsi.en_US.PmiGgqd91Pc.O/am=CQ/d=1/ct=zgms/rs=AF0KOtWwHiXCDsPbTZybnAb2zlX1YPJDGg/m=gis_client_library:109:138)
at /_/gsi/_/js/k=gsi.gsi.en_US.PmiGgqd91Pc.O/am=CQ/d=1/ct=zgms/rs=AF0KOtWwHiXCDsPbTZybnAb2zlX1YPJDGg/m=gis_client_library:299:24
at He.<anonymous> (/_/gsi/_/js/k=gsi.gsi.en_US.PmiGgqd91Pc.O/am=CQ/d=1/ct=zgms/rs=AF0KOtWwHiXCDsPbTZybnAb2zlX1YPJDGg/m=gis_client_library:241:164)
at uc (/_/gsi/_/js/k=gsi.gsi.en_US.PmiGgqd91Pc.O/am=CQ/d=1/ct=zgms/rs=AF0KOtWwHiXCDsPbTZybnAb2zlX1YPJDGg/m=gis_client_library:87:200)
at He._.l.dispatchEvent (/_/gsi/_/js/k=gsi.gsi.en_US.PmiGgqd91Pc.O/am=CQ/d=1/ct=zgms/rs=AF0KOtWwHiXCDsPbTZybnAb2zlX1YPJDGg/m=gis_client_library:85:347)
at Be (/_/gsi/_/js/k=gsi.gsi.en_US.PmiGgqd91Pc.O/am=CQ/d=1/ct=zgms/rs=AF0KOtWwHiXCDsPbTZybnAb2zlX1YPJDGg/m=gis_client_library:179:210)
at Fe (/_/gsi/_/js/k=gsi.gsi.en_US.PmiGgqd91Pc.O/am=CQ/d=1/ct=zgms/rs=AF0KOtWwHiXCDsPbTZybnAb2zlX1YPJDGg/m=gis_client_library:181:245)
at He._.l.zc (/_/gsi/_/js/k=gsi.gsi.en_US.PmiGgqd91Pc.O/am=CQ/d=1/ct=zgms/rs=AF0KOtWwHiXCDsPbTZybnAb2zlX1YPJDGg/m=gis_client_library:186:212)
at He._.l.Nb (/_/gsi/_/js/k=gsi.gsi.en_US.PmiGgqd91Pc.O/am=CQ/d=1/ct=zgms/rs=AF0KOtWwHiXCDsPbTZybnAb2zlX1YPJDGg/m=gis_client_library:186:187)
```

The JS code that throws this error is embedded in a `<script>` tag inside an `<iframe>` that displays the One Tap login popup and it seems to expect an AJAX response with a specific prefix; the statement that throws the error basically looks like this (minified JS):

```
if (!a.startsWith(")]}'\n")) throw console.error("malformed JSON response:", a), Error("A");
```

I checked the network requests and noticed that there is an XHR request that returns the response in this format; the endpoint is https://accounts.google.com/gsi/status (with some extra request parameters) but I cannot find any documentation from google for this endpoint.

Does anyone know would could be the cause of this error?

Thank you

Comment: I've been encountering the same error when running our application in Cypress - no error otherwise. I've not found any documentation around it so far.

Have you had any luck?

Comment: Sorry, I'm afraid not..

Comment: Thanks, I think we'll remove that UI element in test mode to prevent the error.